# Как правильно перебрать массив

Tags: php

Нужна помощь в построении логики как правильно перебрать массив

Например есть массив `1,2,3`

```
$arr = ['1','2','3'];
```

Нужно его перебрать в цикле так, чтобы

Например при первом проходе он брал в переменную `$test1` 1 значение, а в переменную `$test2` все остальные значения

При следующем проходе он брал в переменную `$test1` 2 значение, а все остальные в переменную `$test2`

И при следующем проходу в переменную `$test1` 3 значение, а все остальные в переменную `$test3`

За меня решать не прошу, просто нужно подтолкнуть

Comment: В начале цикла дели массив как тебе нужно. В конце цикла копируй $test2 в $arr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вам нужно получить пары (`1` и `[2,3]`), (`2` и `[1,3]`), (`3` и `[1,2]`) можете это сделать, используя `array_splice`, либо простоый `unset`

```
$data = [1,2,3];
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $test2 = $data;
    $test1 = array_splice($test2, $k, 1);

    print_r(['t1' => $test1[0], 't2' => $test2]);
}
```

или

```
$data = [1,2,3];
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $test1 = $v;
    $test2 = $data;
    unset($test2[$k])

    print_r(['t1' => $test1, 't2' => $test2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> а в переменную $test2 все остальные значения

Считаем, что это значит - "*сложить* все остальные значения".

Найдите сумму всех элементов массива, а потом по очереди вычтите из этой суммы каждый элемент массива.